# How do I get the sed command to evaluate an environment variable?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73312079/why-does-my-sed-command-work-for-one-case-but-not-the-other) , and the answers worked perfectly.  Now, instead of literally passing in what I want to replace with, I would like to pass in an environment variable like so:

```
REPLACE_TWO=two
find . -type f -name "*.conf" -exec sed -i'' -e 's/REPLACE_TWO/$REPLACE_TWO/g' {} +
```

But when I run the above two commands,
mytest.conf gets changed to:

```
displayName: REPLACE_ONE

url: "https://${REPLACE_TWO}:8443"
```

but my desired output is:

```
displayName: REPLACE_ONE

url: "https://two:8443"
```

So for some reason the sed command does not evaluate $REPLACE_TWO.  How do I change the sed command to get it to evaluate the environment variable $REPLACE_TWO?

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes e.g `sed ".....g"` so the variables can expand

Comment: FYI, that's not an environment variable, it's just an ordinary shell variable. It only becomes an environment variable if you `export` it.

Comment: @HatLess - it worked.  if you answer this question I can mark it correct.

Comment: The question is already closed as a duplicate, answers can't be added.

Comment: @Barmar - how do I award points?

Comment: You can't award points here. We don't want to encourage adding answers if there's already an answer somewhere.